# registerForActivityResult: result not delivered if original launcher get destroyed and re-created

Tags: android, registerforactivityresult

I'm replacing deprecated *startActivityForResult* with new *registerForActivityResult*.

Everything works fine, except when i try to manage original launcher being destroyed and re-created.
In fact, as stated [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result):

> the Activity Result APIs decouple the result callback from the place in your code where you launch the other activity.

as

> it is possible (and, in cases of memory-intensive operations such as camera usage, almost certain) that your process and your activity will be destroyed due to low memory.

I'm testing it using *Don't keep activities* feature in *Developer Options*, but i'm starting to think it's not the correct way to go.

In the link i posted there is a *Testing* section, but i didn't undestand why i should use it, as i can test my app simply developing my desired feature.

Here is my code.

In launching activity i wrote, outside every lifecycle method in order to *scanQr* be created before activity is created:

```
private val scanQr = registerForActivityResult(
        ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()
    ) { result: ActivityResult ->
        Toast.makeText(this, "Result obtained", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
```

while second activity is launched here:

```
private fun openCameraForValidation() {
        val intent = Intent(this, ScanQrActivity::class.java)
        scanQr.launch(intent)
    }
```

In the second activity, in order to give back a result, i simply execute this.

```
val dataIntent = Intent()
dataIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_QR_CODE, result ?: "")

setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, dataIntent)
finish()
```

I already tried to call
`scanQr.unregister()`
in first activity OnDestroy, but it didn't make any change.

Could you help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted? If so, how? Thanks.

Comment: @Bink unfortunately no :-(